# How to modify the text in a bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have created a bar chart, with some text inside each bar, now, I would like to knkow if it is possible to modify the size of this text, the font size, in order to reduce it a bit.

I have generated it like this:

```
    #some stuff
    ...
    ...
    rects1 = plt.bar(test, y, bar_width, alpha=opacity, color='b')
    labels = []
    for bar in rects1:
        height = bar.get_height()
        ax.text(bar.get_x()+bar.get_width()/4., 0.65*height, '%.2f'%float(height), rotation='vertical', horizontalalignment='left', va='bottom')
        labels.append(bar.get_x()+bar.get_width()/2.)
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

And the result looks more or less like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't recall `PyQt` has a bar-chart (corret me if I am wrong). Are you using other plotting add-in?

Comment: I think I am not following you....what you see is all that I am using..., at the beginning of the method I use a call to `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, then I create 3 sets of bars, exactly like the code above, rect1, rect2, rect3.. and at the end of the method just some "decorations", `plt.xlabel`, `plt.xlim`, `plt.grid`...etc, and then I just call `return fig`

Comment: Obviously you are using `matplotlib` module, it has nothing to do with `Qt`. You should remove/replace that tag, it's misleading.

Comment: oh yeah, my fault, sorry!! I will remove right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for this: http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html

For instance you can add

```
ax.text(bar.get_x()+bar.get_width()/4., 0.65*height, '%.2f'%float(height), rotation='vertical', horizontalalignment='left', va='bottom', weight='bold')
```

To use a bold font. You can use fontsize=somenumber to change the font size.

Comment: Yes perfect, thanks, I was trying with size=... height=... but no luck...that worked perfect.